# How to do replication with Spring Boot and ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I am looking for a structure or solution that can support spring boot microservices with multiple instances, ActiveMQ Artemis and Apache Camel.

For example:

I have an ActiveMQ Artemis instance and a Spring Boot JMS consumer with instance A (on machine A) and instance B (on machine B).
Both instances (A,B) are up, but by default the instance A is the master consumer, I mean must consume the JMS message and only in case of it's down or it throw some exceptions, the instance B start consuming messages and when A is OK then it take the ball.

Nb: Instance A and B of the Spring Boot microservice are on different machine and in my case i don't have any container like docker etc...

Have you any approach to solve this issue.

Comment: How does "replication" fit in here? Replication in ActiveMQ Artemis refers to broker high availability configuration. Is that what you mean? Please clarify.

Comment: Because i use an external jar in my spring boot whitch have a licence for only one machine, that s why only one instance must consume the jms and not both in same time

Comment: Let me clarify. You mention "replication" in the title of your question, but you don't mention it in the body of the question. In ActiveMQ Artemis "replication" generally refers to a *broker* high availability configuration where data from the master broker is replicated over the network to the slave broker. Is this what you're referring to when you say "replication"? I ask because it appears to me like you talking about having a master/slave *consumer* pair rather than a master/slave broker pair.

Comment: Yes, it's like a master slave in termes of consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you could get to the functionality you want is by using the ["exclusive queue" feature](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/exclusive-queues.html). Both consumers A & B can be active at the same time, but the broker will only send messages to one of them. If the consumer which the broker has chosen goes away for whatever reason then the broker will choose another consumer.